# Display slow data using kendo grid in mvc using HTML5/JavaScript source

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I display my list of data using kendo grid(HTML5/JavaScript source) from my asp.net MVC application.Kendo grid takes too much time to fetch data from a database. I check many demos from google of kendo grid,but I can't get my solution.

```
Front end :- Asp.net MVC
BackEnd :-  MsSql server
code first method to get data from the database.
```

How to track that where it take much time?

**How to display data fast using kendo grid?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a million answers to this question, firstly I'd recommend Chrome Developer tools and take a look what is taking most time. Specificly the "Network" tab.

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

If that isn't what your looking for, Glimpse is an amazing nuget package which will profile the full stack but it takes a bit of configuration.

http://getglimpse.com/

Kendo could be a very small part of your issue. Try using the profiler in Chrome dev tools.

Apart from that I think your question is too broad. You are essentially asking how to debug your application.